# how to os.chdir(" path including non ascii chars like arabic")

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Can any one help me to chdir to a non ascii path, i seached too much for this issue but no result , also i tried to pass the ascii code itself instead of arabic chars but python append a more back slash to each backslash exist and it becomes an invalid path 
e.g :

```
 os.chdir("احمد")
```

also: the real problem when take this path as ain input from raw_input

```
var = raw_input() & assume i put '\xc7\xcd\xe3\xcf'
now ==> var = '\xc7\xcd\xe3\xcf'
os.chdir(var)
```

the ascii chars equiv to "احمد" but it's converted to '\\xc7\\xcd\\xe3\\xcf' cause python think that its a string and include more \ back slah to escape -_-   , any one can help , thanks

Comment: This depends a lot on the OS, and the current `PYTHONIOENCODING` -- which platform are you on? Also, you have tagged both [tag:python-2.7] and [tag:python-3.x] -- if you really require compatibility between Python 2 and Python 3, you should probably at least comment on whether using compatibility tools like `six` is acceptable. But I guess you should simply forget about Python 2, and remove that tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. I use Chinese as an example:

```py
import os

path = '文件'
path_encode = path.encode('UTF-8')
print(path_encode)
# b'\xe6\x96\x87\xe4\xbb\xb6'
os.chdir(path_encode)
```

I think you should just encode احمد to `bytes`, than `os.chdir` will work.

If you have known the bytes as you said, you can just try:

```py
path = b'\xc7\xcd\xe3\xcf'
os.chdir(path)
```